# What is the proper way to install a free/libre kernel?

Tags: installation, kernel, debian

What is the proper way to install, for example, the Debian Squeeze libre kernel in Ubuntu Natty?

Is it safe to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Get the source package from Debian
- Check whether Debian or Ubuntu kernel has non-standard patches
- If the kernel version is different, find out whether this affects userland.
- Compare the configuration and adopt if necessary. (You can use the old .config file from Ubuntu when you `make *config` the new kernel.)
- Compile
- Make binary package through `make-kpkg`
- Repeat for any relevant module
- Install binary packages

However, according to the COPYRIGHT file natty's default kernel is free (licensed GPL): http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux/linux_2.6.38-11.48/copyright

Hence, removing all non-free packages should also meet your goal.